# Inline calculation gives `Could not parse input` error in PGFplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, formatting, calculations, ticks

The inline calculation `exp(\tick)` in PGFplots gives me a `Could not parse input` error when compiling the code

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{loglogaxis}
        [   
            log number format code/.code={\pgfmathprintnumber[sci,sci zerofill,precision=3]{exp(\tick)}}, % GIVES A 'COULD NOT PARSE INPUT' ERROR!
            xtick={1,100}
        ]
            \addplot[no marks,domain=10^0:10^5] {x};
        \end{loglogaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well as the macro name implies it is a pretty-printer not the math parser. You need to do the math outside and supply the result to it. But if you do the regular TikZ parsing the numbers are too big to handle. Hence you need to turn on the `fpu` of TikZ do the math and turn it off.

```
log number format code/.code={%
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}%
    \pgfmathparse{exp(\tick)}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber[sci,sci zerofill,precision=3]{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}%
}
```